# Orocommerce::Purchase price

Tags: orocommerce

As far as I can see there is not possible to calculate profits between our and a purchase prices.
Is it possible to set the purchase price?
It need to adequate calculate net profits along with a revenue.

Comment: An example from the WooCommerce world: https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-cost-of-goods/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with WooCommerce but look at [OroCommerce price attributes](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/products/price-attributes/#create-a-price-attribute) that can be used to store price values that are not rendered to the user storefront so that you can operate them in any custom calculations. And check out the [OroCommerce pricing concept guide](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/concept-guides/pricing/) to understand what capabilities are available in OroCommerce pricing engine.